# Mean, Variance, Standard Variation

Tags: data-analysis

I submitted this question the other week to my tutor, but it was wrong. the only thing correct was the mean. He did not tell me why it was wrong or the correct answers.

Can anybody tell me why this is wrong please? And where I went wrong?

Question and my answer below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why haven´t used more decimal places? For instance: $x_1-\overline x=22.36-22.395=-0.035$ And for the sample variance you have to divide it by 100 I think. As far as I´ve understood the question it is not asked for an unbiased estimator for the variance (of the population).

Comment: Could this be why my answer was incorrect?

Comment: Sure. This could be the problem.

Comment: all the steps look fine, but your teacher could be expecting the proper rounding (show at least four digits after point), notations like $F$ must be $f$, etc. If you don't round and carry out all calculations in MS Excel, the SD will be $0.0128468...$ and the variance will be $0.000165...$. See the difference?

Comment: @KyleAnderson, you are correct about my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your method is correct. However, one place you might have messed up is rounding $\bar{x}=22.3981$ to $22.39$, when it is actually closer to $22.40$, as this might've messed up your answer.  You should keep the value as $22.3981$ during calculations.

Comment: So recalculate with 22.3981 then this would of been correct?

Comment: yup it should be right then

Comment: I don't think that this causes the instructor to say the answer is wrong.

Comment: but it had to have created a large enough error, and maybe the instructor was simply scanning the answers @NoChance

Comment: He did say tiny errors. So maybe this could be why. If so that is so frustrating. I thought they was a big mistake, hence why I asked on this forum.

Comment: @NoChance can you see any other errors that would cause me to fail?

Comment: @KyleAnderson, pls check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the formulas from [This Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/how-do-i-calculate-a-weighted-standard-deviation-in-excel), I noticed that the formulas are different from what you are using, specially in the denominator of the Variance.

I  obtained the following values:

[image]